# Android phone dosn't get an ip address from a router that has no internet connection

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-wifi, router

I have an custom embedded computer (CEC) connected to a wireless router (Linksys) who I want to communicate with using an Android phone (LG Nexus 5) via. TCP/IP over WiFi. The router is not connected to the internet and is only used as a WiFi hotspot the phone can connect to.

When the phone connects to the router it says "connected - no internet" and the phone don't get an ip address, or so it seems, more on this later.

I can't ping the router from the phone, and it dosn't seem to work. If I connect the router to the internet, everything works perfect.

My theory is that the phone always uses a connection with internet as default, because it still is connected to the net via. the the phones connection. If I enable fly mode on the phone and turn on WiFi, the phone gets an IP address from the router and everything works.

I have made an App in Xamarin.Forms where I call a method that returns all ip addresses the phone is using, an here is the right ip address present, despite the phone claims it has no ip address from the router, so it is in the system some how.

So how do I force the Android phone to use the right ip address it has from the router.

Comment: This is likely an Android issue, not something you can fix programmatically.  See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66964/connect-to-wifi-network-even-if-it-doesnt-have-internet-access

Comment: Had the same problem on windows phone and solved it by forcing it to use the right network adapter.... I think there must be someting like this on Android too